# Finding a cycle and saving its vertices in an undirected, unweighted graph using BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I've been trying to make this program save the vertices that make the cycle in the graph. But I'm kind of a newbie in algorithms and achieving that functionality seems a bit complex when using BFS. The code below successfully finds cycles, but the question is how to modify this code so I can print all the vertices that make the cycle?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}
 
bool isCyclicConntected(vector<int> adj[], int s,
                        int V, vector<bool>& visited)
{
    // Set parent vertex for every vertex as -1.
    vector<int> parent(V, -1);
 
    // Create a queue for BFS
    queue<int> q;
 
    // Mark the current node as
    // visited and enqueue it
    visited[s] = true;
    q.push(s);
 
    while (!q.empty()) {
 
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
 
        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued
        // vertex u. If a adjacent has not been visited,
        // then mark it visited and enqueue it. We also
        // mark parent so that parent is not considered
        // for cycle.
        for (auto v : adj[u]) {
            if (!visited[v]) {
                visited[v] = true;
                q.push(v);
                parent[v] = u;
            }
            else if (parent[u] != v)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 
bool isCyclicDisconntected(vector<int> adj[], int V)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    vector<bool> visited(V, false);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (!visited[i] && isCyclicConntected(adj, i,
                                         V, visited))
            return true;
    return false;
}
 
// Driver program to test methods of graph class
int main()
{
    int V = 4;
    vector<int> adj[V];
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 0);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3);
 
    if (isCyclicDisconntected(adj, V))
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Currently your `isCyclicDisconntected` function returns `true` when there is a cycle. This is the opposite from what you would expect from a function with that name (even when the spelling is fixed).

Comment: Nodes in an undirected graph do not have a parent.  Rename `parent` to `predecessor`.  When you find a cycle, backtrack through `predecessor` printing out the nodes in the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `parent` links to reconstruct the cycle.

When two BFS paths meet, then these two paths can each be reconstructed by following the `parent` link in tandem, until a common node is encountered. The lengths of these two paths can either be equal (the cycle is even), or differ by 1 (the cycle is odd). If you do the tandem walk via the mutual `parent` links in the right way, you will always encounter the "top" of the cycle.

The nodes of the cycle will be listed in a natural order when you use a deque: the nodes coming from the first path can be pushed to the front, while the nodes of the other path to the back.

You don't actually need a separate `visited` vector: you can also use `parent` for this purpose. True, the first node you start the BFS on, will then not be marked as visited, but there is no way to visit it as the end point of a cycle, as BFS will go through *all* edges from that source node, and does not allow to use any of those edges to visit the source node. So using `parent` for that purpose is enough.

Here is your code adapted with those ideas:

```
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}
 
bool isCyclicConnectedHelper(vector<int> adj[], int s,
                            int V, vector<int>& parent,
                            deque<int> &cycle)
{
    queue<int> q;
 
    q.push(s);
 
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (auto v : adj[u]) {
            if (parent[v] == -1) { // Not yet visited
                parent[v] = u;
                q.push(v);
            }
            else if (parent[u] != v) { // Not the same edge
                // Two paths meet: unwind both of them at both sides of a deque:
                while (u != v) {
                    cycle.push_front(v);
                    v = parent[v];
                    if (u == v) break;
                    cycle.push_back(u);
                    u = parent[u];
                }
                cycle.push_front(u);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 
bool isCyclicConnected(vector<int> adj[], int V, deque<int> &cycle)
{
    vector<int> parent(V, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (parent[i] == -1) {
            if (isCyclicConnectedHelper(adj, i, V, parent, cycle)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 
// Driver program to test methods of graph class
int main()
{
    int V = 5;
    vector<int> adj[V];
    addEdge(adj, 0, 1);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 3, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 4, 1);
 
    deque<int> cycle;
    if (isCyclicConnected(adj, V, cycle)) {
        cout << "The graph has a cycle:";
        for (auto v : cycle) {
            cout << " " << v;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "The graph has no cycle.";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

NB: I would suggest defining `adj` as `vector<vector<int>>` and adjust `addEdge` so it will extend that vector as needed. That way you also get rid of `V`.